# Connection error when deploying with flightplan

Tags: node.js

I am running this code with flightplan:

```
var plan = require('flightplan');

var appName = 'personal-website';
var username = 'deploy';
var startFile = 'bin/www';

var tmpDir = appName+'-' + new Date().getTime();

// configuration
plan.target('staging', [
  {
    host: '104.131.153.117',
    username: username,
  }
]);

plan.target('production', [
  {
    host: '104.131.153.117',
    username: username,
  },
//add in another server if you have more than one
// {
//   host: '104.131.93.216',
//   username: username,
//   agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK
// }
]);

// run commands on localhost
plan.local(function(local) {
  local.log('Copy files to remote hosts');
  var filesToCopy = local.exec('git ls-files', {silent: true});
  // rsync files to all the destination's hosts
  local.transfer(filesToCopy, '/tmp/' + tmpDir);
});

// run commands on remote hosts (destinations)
plan.remote(function(remote) {
  remote.log('Move folder to root');
  remote.sudo('cp -R /tmp/' + tmpDir + ' ~', {user: username});
  remote.rm('-rf /tmp/' + tmpDir);

  remote.log('Install dependencies');
  remote.sudo('npm --production --prefix ~/' + tmpDir + ' install ~/' + tmpDir, {user: username});

  remote.log('Reload application');
  remote.sudo('ln -snf ~/' + tmpDir + ' ~/'+appName, {user: username});
  remote.exec('forever stop ~/'+appName+'/'+startFile, {failsafe: true});
  remote.exec('forever start ~/'+appName+'/'+startFile);
});
```

This is the error I get when I try to deploy:

```
Error connecting to 104.131.153.117: Error: Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey,password
```

I have no idea what going on. I am trying to deploy this to digital ocean. I am not sure what is causing this problem.

Comment: Looks like you're having trouble with `ssh` somewhere in this process, but that could be `git` complaining it can't pull your repo. Are you sure you have all the right keys in place? If you need to do `git` commands on your server, you need to have registered keys there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't authenticated to your remote host properly. You need to add your SSH key to the remote host for password-free access.

The command to do this is

```
$ ssh-copy-id <user>@<host>
```

If you need to specify an exact key to use, use the following command

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i <path-to-.pub-file> <user>@<host>
```